# Add balance in arraylists

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have a BankAccont `arraylist`

```
public class JFrameNewAccount extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private List<BankAccount> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and a BankAccount Class

```
public class BankAccount {
    private String accountNo;
    private String accountName;
    protected double balance; 
    private String accountType;

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Also, I have a button in my `JFrameNewAccount` that will saved the data in an `arraylists`.

```
private void btnSaveAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    BankAccount account = new BankAccount();

    account.setAccountName(txt_accountname.getText());
    account.setAccountNo(txt_accountnumber.getText());

    list.add(account);
}
```

I have a txt_initialbalance for balance, my problem is, how can I add the txt_initialbalance in my arraylists account.

Comment: Why not doing it the same way as you add accountname and accountnumber?

Comment: While not relevant to your problem, I would just like to point out that it's never ever a good idea to store currency as a floating point number due to rounding errors. (Doing so when dealing with real money is even illegal in some places from what I understand.) An integer type (to store amount of cents) or a proper decimal number type should ALWAYS be used.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write setter and getter methods for all properties in BankAccount class...
after that your code will be as follows:

```
BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
account.setBalance(txt_initialbalance); //This is the setter that should be added
list.add(account);
```

Comment: I would assume that `txt_initialbalance` is `JTextField` like `txt_accountname`, which isn't going to fit well with the `balance` method....

Comment: I've tried that, but balance datatype is double, it gives me an error. txt_initialbalance is String

Comment: try... account.setBalance(Double.parseDouble(txt_initialbalance.geText()))

Comment: I tried `account.setBalance(Double.parseDouble(txt_initialbalance.getText()));` but it gives me an error: Method setBalance in Class BankAccount cannot be applied to given types, required: no arguments, found: double, reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length

Comment: change your setBalance() method BankAccount class to setBalance(double balance){ this .balance = balance; }

Comment: Thanks All! I've got it now. Highly Appreciated all your comments! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `BankAccount` class to provide (possibly via the constructor) an initial balance value...

Something like...

```
public class BankAccount { 
    // Declarations...
    public BankAccount(double initalBalance) {
        balance = initalBalance;
    }
}
```

Then when you want to construct a new `BankAccount`, you will need to parse the value from the text field...

```
double balance = 0;
try {
    balance = Double.parseDouble(txt_initialbalance.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}

BankAccount account = new BankAccount(balance);
```

I would also suggest you take a look at [How to use spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html), as it will help prevent you from running it problems with parsing the results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the String value of the text field to a Double value, like this:

```
account.setBalance(Double.valueOf(txt_initialbalance.getText());
```